# Is it possible to get service tag from laptop via JavaScript web application?

Tags: javascript, angular, service, tags

I am trying to build website (using Angular framework) that will search Dell Drivers from their website. User then will able to download them and install. However, there are many different laptops with different drivers. Each laptop has service tag from which you can identify which drivers system needs.

I currently trying to make my website scan the system for service tag. I don't know how to do that. I tried to search the web for libraries that will allow me to do it. But unfortunately I did not find any. Are there any libraries that will help?

Comment: JavaScript, running in a browser, is not allow to access the file system. You would need a native application to do this.

Comment: Read about electron.js .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several data that you may be able to read using a browser. It again depends on the client whether they have already given permission for that in their browser.

Check this site, they are trying to read a lot of system data just with javascript. Browsers won't let you access the file system but it has much other information that might be of your interest.

https://webkay.robinlinus.com/

You can check the page source and see what script they are using. You may not be able to read the service tag but there are other data you may be able to use. eg: Operating system.

The above website uses a library.

https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js

Service Tag is definitely not part of it, so I would suggest, giving the user an option to input the service tag. You will have to guide the user on how to get the tag details as a help text.

Now with OS and other available details from the User-Agent Parser, you may be able to suggest the right driver for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely possible as Dell does it on their website.

https://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukdhs1?app=products

Press the `Detect PC` button which will somehow find your service tag client side. It works in both Chrome and Firefox.

I don't know how it works under the hood.